# Angular Error al generar una coleccion

Tags: angular, typescript

el día de hoy vengo a solicitar vuestra ayuda para un problema en Angular al crear un metodo llamado getClientes para extraer datos desde la bd en Firestore.

```
adjunto error:
```

> El tipo
> 'import("c:/Angular/control-clientes/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Observable").Observable<import("c:/Angular/control-clientes/src/app/modelo/cliente.model").Cliente[]>'
> no se puede asignar al tipo
> 'import("c:/Angular/control-clientes/node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/util-public").Observable<import("c:/Angular/control-clientes/src/app/modelo/cliente.model").Cliente[]>'.
> Los tipos que "subscribe(...)" devuelve son incompatibles entre estos tipos.
> El tipo 'Subscription' no se puede asignar al tipo 'Unsubscribe'.
> El tipo "Subscription" no proporciona ninguna coincidencia para la signatura "(): void".

Adjunto codigo: el error se da en el inicio de this.clientes =

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from "@angular/fire/compat/firestore";
import { Observable } from "@firebase/util";
import { Cliente } from "../modelo/cliente.model";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

//Si se usan servicios de otras clases, se usa Injectable
@Injectable()

export class ClienteServicio{
    clientesColeccion: AngularFirestoreCollection<Cliente>;
    clienteDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Cliente>;
    clientes: Observable<Cliente[]>;
    cliente: Observable<Cliente>;
    

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore){
        this.clientesColeccion = db.collection('clientes', ref => ref.orderBy('nombre', 'asc'));
    }

    getClientes(): Observable<Cliente[]>{
        //Obtener los clientes
        this.clientes = this.clientesColeccion.snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map( cambios => {
                return cambios.map( accion => {
                    const datos = accion.payload.doc.data() as Cliente;
                    datos.id = accion.payload.doc.id;
                    return datos;
                })
            })
        );
        return this.clientes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta importación está mal:

```
import { Observable } from "@firebase/util";
```

Se debe importar `Observable` desde `rxjs`:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```